# how do I set up a route for my custom pages to work (CORE v5.7.12)?

Tags: html-framework-7

I have been using Framework7 v.1 and I would to upgrade to the latest version but I can’t seem to make it to work.

I need a sample code for a working custom routes and pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If [doc's examples](https://framework7.io/docs/routes.html) are not enough, you can check [kitchen-sink](https://github.com/framework7io/framework7/tree/master/kitchen-sink/core) code, which is a demo app, containing all Framework7 components including various routing approaches.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but I had already checked the Kitchen-Sink but there's no custom route included! https://github.com/framework7io/framework7/blob/master/kitchen-sink/core/js/routes.js

Comment: Okay, what do you mean by “custom route”?

Comment: I thought it was smth like `path: '(.*)'`

Answer (score 0):

Just write a route for that in routes.js and call it with anchor tag.
eg :

```
in routes.js ,{ page:'data-name-of-page', url:'path/to-that/page-location'},...
in index.html <a href="/path/to-that/page-location/" class="link">Take me to page</a>
```